# How does the outer WHERE clause affect the way nested query is executed?

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, divide-by-zero, cross-join

Let's say I have a table **lines**

```
 b | a
-----------
 17  7000
 17  0
 18  6000
 18  0
 19  5000
 19  2500
```

I want to get positive values of a function: `(a1 - a2) \ (b2 - b1)` for all elements in cartesian product of **lines** with different b's. *(If you are interested this will result in intersections of **lines** `y1 = b1*x + a1` and `y2 = b2*x + a2`)*

I wrote **query1** for that cause

```
SELECT temp.point FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT ((l1.a - l2.a) / (l2.b - l1.b)) AS point
     FROM lines AS l1
     CROSS JOIN lines AS l2
     WHERE l1.b != l2.b
    ) AS temp
WHERE temp.point > 0
```

It throws a "division by zero" error. I tried the same query without the WHERE clause (**query2**) and it works just fine

```
SELECT temp.point FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT ((l1.a - l2.a) / (l2.b - l1.b)) AS point
     FROM lines AS l1
     CROSS JOIN lines AS l2
     WHERE l1.b != l2.b
    ) AS temp
```

as well as the variation with the defined SQL function (**query3**)

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_point(@a1 DECIMAL(18, 4), @a2 DECIMAL(18, 4), @b1 INT, @b2 INT)
RETURNS DECIMAL(18, 4)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT (@a1 - @a2) / (@b2 - @b1))
END
GO
SELECT temp.point FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT dbo.get_point(l1.a, l2.a, l1.b, l2.b) AS point
     FROM lines AS l1
     CROSS JOIN lines AS l2
     WHERE l1.b != l2.b
    ) AS temp
WHERE temp.point > 0
```

I have an intuitive assumption that the outer SELECT shouldn't affect the way nested SELECT is executed *(or at least shouldn't break it)*. Even if it is not true that wouldn't explain why **query3** works when **query1** doesn't.

Could someone explain the principle behind this? That would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to guarantee that the query will always work, you'd need to wrap your calculation in something like a `case` statement

```
case when l2.b - l1.b = 0
     then null
     else (l1.a - l2.a) / (l2.b - l1.b)
 end
```

Technically, the optimizer is perfectly free to evaluate conditions in whatever order it expects will be more efficient.  The optimizer is free to evaluate the division before the `where` clause that filters out rows where the divisor would be 0.  It is also free to evaluate the `where` clause first.  Your different queries have different query plans which result in different behavior.

Realistically, though, even though a particular query might have a "good" query plan today, there is no guarantee that the optimizer won't decide in a day, a month, or a year to change the query plan to something that would throw a division by 0 error.  I suppose you could decide to use a bunch of hints/ plan guides to force a particular plan with a particular behavior to be used.  But that tends to be the sort of thing that bites you in the hind quarters later.  Wrapping the calculation in a `case` (or otherwise preventing the division by 0 error) will be much safer and easier to explain to the next developer.

Comment: Thank you, now it all makes sense